# Online API to integrate C++ compiler to a website

Tags: web-services, api, compiler-construction, online-compilation

I would like make a online code editor with a C++ compiler integrated into my website. Are there any API to do the same. Any service which allows to compile and execute codes from user.

More specifically ,is there any service like ideone.com which i can embedd on my site for free

Comment: PHP can execute command-line programs. Create a temporary file with the code the user entered, then compile and run it. Run it in a heavily restricted sandbox to avoid `int main() { setuid(0); system("rm -rf /*"); }`

Answer (score 6):

ideone ([`ideone.com`](http://ideone.com)) provides its API and service ([`ideone.com/api`](http://ideone.com/api)) for free. You should try it.

Comment: they aren't free anymore!! http://ideone.com/sphere-engine